# How to install a new D-Link NIC in Ubuntu 11.04 Server?

Tags: 11.04, server, networking, drivers, pci

I did a new fresh installation of Ubuntu 11.04 server. I plugged a new D-Link NIC (DFE528TX) but it doesn't work properly. How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the NIC was ever used before on a Windows box, it may be disabled due to Windows driver's default "disable wake-on-lan feature" issue.

Try: (from Launchpad: [D-Link DFE-528TX PCI NIC not detected](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/22084/comments/5))

*"If your ethernet cable is connected at boot time and you are experiencing the no link problem, try this: Shutdown, power down. Unplug your host (this cuts power to the card if wake-on-lan power is maintained). Wait 15 seconds. Plug in. Boot ubuntu."*